# How to set the speed of audio in media element?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

My objective is to increase the speed of audio.Is there any way to achieve this in winRT media element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 properties you can use:

```
 MediaElement.DefaultPlaybackRate
```

which will persist throughout the application session and

```
 MediaElement.PlaybackRate
```

which will be lost after every Pause() or Stop() calls.
They are both of type `double` and default to 1.0